# java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.lang.instrument.Instrumentation.getObjectSize(Object)" because "ObjectSizeFetcher.instrumentation"

Tags: java

I am trying to use [getObjectSize](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.instrument/java/lang/instrument/Instrumentation.html#getObjectSize(java.lang.Object)) to measure memory in Java. I am using JDK-20. I have done everything according to what [documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52682/147530) I could find online. I have my instrumentation class:

```
package com.github.jelmerk;

import java.lang.instrument.Instrumentation;
 
public class ObjectSizeFetcher {
    private static Instrumentation instrumentation;
 
    public static void premain(String args, Instrumentation inst) {
        System.out.println("initializing ObjectSizeFetcher...");
        if (inst == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("unable to initialize ObjectSizeFetcher. java.lang.instrument.Instrumentation is null");
        }
        instrumentation = inst;
        System.out.println("successfully initialized ObjectSizeFetcher");
    }
 
    public static long getObjectSize(Object o) {
        return instrumentation.getObjectSize(o);
    }
}
```

then in `pom.xml` I have defined the `PreMain-class`:

```
<plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.2</version>
          <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <packageName>com.github.jelmerk</packageName>
            </manifest>
            <manifestEntries>
                <Premain-Class>com.github.jelmerk.ObjectSizeFetcher</Premain-Class>
            </manifestEntries>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

I then installed the jar into M2 repository. I am setting the `javaagent` in my application:

```
MAVEN_OPTS="-javaagent:/my/.m2/repository/my/package/memory-profiler/1.2.0/memory-profiler-1.2.0.jar --enable-preview --add-modules jdk.incubator.vector -enableassertions" \
mvn exec:java -Dexec.cleanupDaemonThreads=false
```

but when I run my application I get this:

```
% ./run.sh
WARNING: Using incubator modules: jdk.incubator.vector
initializing ObjectSizeFetcher...
successfully initialized ObjectSizeFetcher
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ----------------------< com.mycompany.app:my-app >----------------------
[INFO] Building my-app 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO]   from pom.xml
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- exec:3.1.0:java (default-cli) @ my-app ---
[WARNING]
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.lang.instrument.Instrumentation.getObjectSize(Object)" because "com.github.jelmerk.ObjectSizeFetcher.instrumentation" is null
    at com.github.jelmerk.ObjectSizeFetcher.getObjectSize (ObjectSizeFetcher.java:18)
    at com.mycompany.app.App.main (App.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run (ExecJavaMojo.java:279)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:1623)
```

Note I even this message:

```
initializing ObjectSizeFetcher...
successfully initialized ObjectSizeFetcher
```

yet when I try to call `getObjectSize` it returns NPE. Can someone tell me what is wrong here and how can I fix it? I have tried debugging for many hours.

Answer (score 1):

Agents get their own classloader which is independent from the 'main application' classloader.

2 separate classloaders can actually each load the same class, resulting in 1 class being loaded *twice*, i.e. every `static` variable exists twice.

Thus, here, your agent initializes and prints what you see. Then from your main app you call `ObjectSizeFetcher.getObjectSize()` which causes a second completely independent ObjectSizeFetcher to load, which, of course, still has `null` as value for its static `Instrumentation instrumentation` field.

This isn't what agents are designed for - you're not supposed to talk to a running agent like this.

Given that you are an agent, if you want to try it anyway and hack around it (though I bet you'll run into more roadblocks, given that this isn't what it was meant for), well, you're an agent: You can rewrite things. In particular, you should be able to override the class load mechanism and 'catch' the loading of one of the app classes, which gives your agent a `Class<?>` instance. Make a separate class that looks like this:

```
public class Container {
  public static ClassLoader agentLoader;
}
```

And set your own loader. Now your app-side code can fetch the agent loader, use that to get a ref to the ObjectSizeFetcher, and use reflection to invoke `getObjectSize`.